# как мне узнать текст сообщения discord.py

Tags: python, бот, discord.py

я хочу узнать текст сообщения и имя пользователя,
но по какой-то причине вместо текста мне выдаёт это "<built-in method startswith of str object at 0x00000213ED7BE010>"

```
import discord
from config import TOKEN
from discord.ext import commands

intents = discord.Intents.default()
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='/', intents=intents)

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    caller = message.author
    caller = str(caller)
    print(f'Сообщение: {str(message.content.startswith)}, имя: {caller}')

bot.run(TOKEN)
```

Comment: А что вы хотите получить от свойства (метода?) `startswith`? Почему именно `message.content.startswith`, а не `message.startswith` или просто `message`?

Answer (score 1):

А что вы хотели получить от `startswith` в `message.content.startswith`?

> Исправьте `message.content.startswith` на `message.content`:

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    print(f'Сообщение: {message.content}, имя: {message.author.name}')
```

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/842418)

Comment: Это ответ на вопрос. Ошибка была получена из-за того, что он использует `message.content.startswith`, что вообще выводит не понятно что и не понятно что он от этого хотел. Достаточно было использовать `message.content` на что я и указал в ответе.